# How to fetch results from a single table with the two fields and one having duplicate values in mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with different fields, but I want to display the results of two fields and one contains duplicate values. Consider:

```
  F1  |   F2
-----------------
m1    | manchester
m2    | manchester 
cm3   | london
k4    | birmingham
```

I want the result in such a way that if I press <kbd>m</kbd>

```
m1
m2
cm3
manchester
birmingham
```

I am new to php & mysql

Comment: I have edited the answer to show your tables as *code* which preserves the formatting that you so nicely included in your question. You can easily keep formatting by pressing the `{}` icon or indenting the characters by four spaces or a tab and keeping an empty line above and below the text you want to preserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union query to get what you want like this:

```
select
    F1 as m
from 
    tableName
where
    F1 like '%m%'
union all
select
    F2 as m
from 
    tableName
where
    F2 like '%m%'
```

Edit: This will automatically remove duplicates as shown below:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | ffff  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from first union select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | ffff  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UNION DISTINCT`?

Comment: I wrote the query in such a way tht
select f1, DISTINCT f2 as f2 from table where f1 LIKE 'm' or f2 LIKE 'm'

Comment: @inhan The union will automatically select distinct columns as I recently found out. I gave you an example from my SO database that I use for testing/examples. It spun me out when I saw it like that for the first time let me tell you :)

Comment: @haileyTurlapati I have updated my answer to include your `where` clause from the comment :)

Comment: @Fluffeh thanks for clarifying that point. I thought it picked distinct *values* instead.

Comment: @inhan All good sir, I found that out myself from an answer here on SO a few weeks ago after using `distinct` clauses for years :)

Comment: The LIKE clauses should be `LIKE '%m%'`, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, good point, I copied the OPs code from the comment. Updated Answer.